# Excel VBA Replace Character

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I tried looking around for this particular problem, but couldn't find it.

I am trying to replace an assortment of characters in a string.

I tried looping through the characters using their character codes, but my code will ?randomly? delete the entire string instead of just the special characters. (basically I just want the letters and numbers from the string)

> ABC-3.3%H14T-6

I would just want

> ABC33H14T6

What is strange about this (to me) is that my code will delete the string on a random character, it's not always `chr(41)` or whatever, it changes each time I run the code.. is it maybe a formatting issue?

```
 For Char = 33 To 47
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(FRow, 44).Replace What:=Chr(Char), Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart
 Next Char
```

I would give you the bulk of my code, but it is work-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the way you do it won't work, since these non-alphanumeric charcters may have special functions, like jokers etc. You need to replace within VBA, not within Excel.

So try this instead:

```
For Char = 33 To 47
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(FRow, 44).Value = Replace(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(FRow, 44).Value, Chr(Char), "")
Next Char
```

Comment: I think regex replacing would be faster instead of looping through char code.

Answer (score 0):

something like this [regexp](/questions/tagged/regexp)

```
Sub test()
MsgBox KillChars("ABC-3.3%H14T-6")
End Sub

Function KillChars(strIn As String) As String
Dim objRegex
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
.Pattern = "[^\w]+"
.Global = True
KillChars = .Replace(strIn, vbNullString)
End With
End Function
```